# Java fxml does not sync with target folder

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

If i make some changes in my src folder, the changes do not update in the target folder. So i have already tried to copy my files from the src folder in the target folder, but they have different filetypes. Therefore i can't write in the target-folder (read only).

**What can i do that these two folders update.?**

For example, if i create new labels, circle objects. i can't see them after running, because the file that is being executed still has the old version.

i have already tried to sync these files with copy paste or delet the target folder. Nothing worked.

Comment: Don't manually try to copy from source to target.  Use the [maven standard layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) (even if you aren't using maven).  Put your source under `src/main/java` and your resources under `src/main/resources`.  While you can configure the source and resource paths manually in an IDE, I advise using a build tool (use Maven rather than Gradle if you have never used a build tool).  Import the build tool project into your IDE.

Comment: Idea will do all of the stuff automatically for you when you create a [new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), which I advise you do as it is the easiest way (IMO) to get a functional new FXML based development environment correctly setup.

Comment: i have checked these paths and they are already like you said. ...

Comment: Then your project isn't correctly configured to use standard paths.

Comment: Once you have your project settings correctly configured, study, understand and follow the [eden resource guide](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/) which details different strategies on where to place resources and how to look them up and find them.

Answer (score -2):

You have to look in the Wiki from HTl at Austria, the author samcrewo has done a very good work. It is very easy to understand and you can copy the most of it to your programm. Hope I have helped you!

Comment: This is truely interesting and helpful, but still should have written as comment. Also in an answer put not only a link, which might disappear a year later. Nevertheless keep at it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t concur with Joop.  I used Google and could not even find the referenced wiki or any information at all relevant to the question, so this was not helpful for me.